# Condition for watermark interval for batch data in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have two sources of data-`itemDetails`, `admitDetails` which come in batch mode. Sometimes this batch mode contains historical data as well. We are using Spark Structured Streaming which ingests data as soon as batch data arrives. We are using two individual `readStream` to read data for `itemDetails` & `admitDetails` from a script.
I am using `inner join` between `itemDetails` and `admitDetails` to access patient details. Earlier we were not using watermark for inner join, as this is optional in Structured Streaming. But this is resulting huge state size which keeps increasing. So, I am thinking to use it now.

event time column is as follow:
`admitDetails ==> admit_timestamp`
`itemDetails ==> transaction_timestamp`

Problem is that sequence of event is not fixed. Mostly `admitDetails` event will occur first(more than 90% of cases) which implies that:
`admit_timestamp < transaction_timestamp` (diff is mostly 30 min to 8 hours max).

But `itemDetails` event can also occur first which implies that:
`admit_timestamp > transaction_timestamp` (This difference can be max of 7 days)

To overcome this, I am subtracting 10 days from `admit_timestamp` for all records of `admitDetails`. This will make sure `admit_timestamp` is always first event. I am using below code:

**watermark for `admit_timestamp`:**

```scala
admitDf = admitDf.withColumn("admit_timestamp",
      to_timestamp(col("admit_timestamp"),"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a"))
      .withColumn("admit_timestamp", expr("timestamp(admit_timestamp) - interval 10 days"))
      .withWatermark("admit_timestamp", "10 seconds")
```

**watermark for `transaction_timestamp`:**

```scala
transactionDf = transactionDf.withColumn("transaction_timestamp",
      to_timestamp(col("transaction_timestamp"),"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a"))
      .withWatermark("transaction_timestamp", "10 seconds")
```

**Join Condition:**

```scala
val joined_stream = admitDf
      .join(transactionDf, expr(
        """transaction_key = admit_key AND
          |transaction_timestamp >= admit_timestamp AND
          |transaction_timestamp <= admit_timestamp + interval 12 days
          """.stripMargin),
        joinType = "inner")
```

But the above code is not working as per expectation. Very less number of records are coming to sink in compare to when executing without watermark script with the same set of data.
Here I just want to clear the state while inner join operation. There is no in/out of order events based on event time in my use case. So no rows should get drop based on time range condition. Please help.